# Swagger-codegen get started

Tags: rest, sdk, swagger, codegen

I'm looking to get into Swagger, more specifically, the swagger-codegen tool. I find the provided information, documentation and specs in both github and http://swagger.io/ to be rather confusing (plus, some links to code examples were broken /404/). Is there any portal where I can see some get started tutorials, code examples, etc aimed for beginners, using these tools?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Swagger-Codegen github page contains a section showing how to generate a [sample client](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen#to-generate-a-sample-client-library).

Assuming you've the Swagger spec, you can also generate the API client online. Here is an example:

```
curl -X POST -H "content-type:application/json" -d '{"swaggerUrl":"http://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json"}' http://generator.swagger.io/api/gen/servers/spring-mvc
```

For broken links in the swagger-codegen's github page, please report the issue [here](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues)

UPDATE: On May 2018, about 50 top contributors and template creators of Swagger Codegen decided to fork Swagger Codegen to maintain a community-driven version called [OpenAPI Generator](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator). Please refer to the [Q&A](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/docs/qna.md) for more information.